# Linnworks API Auth

Tags: php, api, authentication

I am having trouble with the Auth method of the Linnworks API http://apps.linnworks.net/Api, I can't seem to make the Authorization request to their server correct.

I see that in the documentation it is stated that there are two ways to connect, one is by an application token and the other is by username and password if you are making a single use application (that's what I am doing).

By looking around in Google I found a Linnworks PHP SDK in GitHub in which I saw that the auth method for the basic username/password authentication is Auth/Authorize. Unfortunately this method is NOT mentioned in their documentation.

When I tried to user their PHP SDK with my account credentials, I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.linnworks.net/api/Auth/Authorize): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

The code:

```
include 'Factory.php';
include 'Classes/Auth.php';

$auth = new AuthMethods();
$resp = $auth->Authorize('email', 'password', 'userid'); //hidden
```

I gave up on their PHP SDK.

I saw in the documentation that they have a test method called Auth/GetServerUTCTime where you can see if you connect successfully to their API. I tried to make a cURL call to it and everything was okay, I got a response.

When I changed the url and tried to make a post request to Auth/Authorize I got again the same error:

```
Error: 400: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

The code:

```
$curl = new Curl();
$curl->post('https://api.linnworks.net/api/Auth/Authorize', array(
            'userName' => 'email',
            'password' => 'password',
            'userId'   => userid
));
```

So basically I'm stuck on the Authorization. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you manage to do thi

Comment: Have u got solution for above issue ?

Comment: ¿I Presume you resolved yourself but didn't post?